# Python: Count Frequency in List and aligned the result

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, list, counter

I have a list of a random word as a string and I need to count the frequency of it.

```
a = ['a','ccc','bb','ccc','a','ccc','bb','bb','a','bb']
```

I want to make it into a loop. So the output will be

```
   1 a          3
   2 bb         4
   3 ccc        3
```

with the number is aligned in the right with 4 spaces or character in the left, elements on the list are aligned in the left with 5 characters in the left and the frequency aligned in the right like above.

I know how to count the frequency but I don't know how to arrange them

```
total_word = {}
for word in clear_word:
    if word not in total_word:
        total_word[word] = 0
    total_word[word] += 1
```

Sorry to interrupt

Answer (score 3):

There are at least two efficient ways:

```
from collections import Counter, defaultdict
a = ['a','ccc','bb','ccc','a','ccc','bb','bb','a','bb']
# method 1:
d = defaultdict(int)
for elem in a:
    d[elem] += 1
for ctr, k in enumerate(sorted(d), start = 1):
    print(ctr,k,'\t',d[k])

# method 2:
d = Counter(a)
for ctr, k in enumerate(sorted(d), start = 1):
    print(ctr,k,'\t',d[k])
```

Output:

```
1 a      3
2 bb     4
3 ccc    3
```

EDIT: 
Here you go:

```
a = ['a','ccc','bb','ccc','a','ccc','bb','bb','a','bb']
unique = sorted(set(a))
for ctr, i in enumerate(unique,start=1):
    print(ctr,i,'\t',a.count(i))
```

Comment: Please check the edit, if you need without dict, but most probably will be slower for large lists.

Answer (score 1):

Try this, using [collections.Counter](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/collections.html#collections.Counter)

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> i=1
>>> for k, v in Counter(a).items():
        print(f"{i:<3} {k:<10} {v}")
        i+=1
```

---

**Output:**

```
1   a          3
2   ccc        3
3   bb         4
```

Comment: I believe he knows how to compute the frequency, the OP is looking for a way of displaying the data

Answer (score 1):

If you like me occasionally have to work on python less then 2.6 you could use oldscool string-formatting like:

```
print "%3s %-10s %s" % (i, the_word, count)
```

Here:

- `%3s` will occupy 3 characters and get you left aligned text
- `%-10s` will occupy 10 characters and be right (the minus sign) aligned

This formatting will work in any python-version.

Comment: Why use this over f-strings or `.format()`?

Comment: As stated in my message, this is "oldscool". But its working and if you grew up using other ancient things like C or `awk` that notation is more familiar. But of course you should preferably learn the `.format()` notation since it gives you greater power and flexibility.

Answer (score 0):

Hi based on your code this loop display your results

```
for a in total_word.keys():
     print(a ,'\t',  total_word[a])
```

This my output

```
 a       3
 bb      4
 ccc     3
```

Answer (score 0):

You can align your columns using f-strings (see [here](https://pyformat.info/#string_pad_align) to understand the `:>{padding}`):

```
padding = max(len(word) for word in total_word.keys()) + 1
for word, count in total_word.items():
    print(f"{word:<{padding}}{count:>3}")
```

if you wanted the index as well then add in `enumerate`:

```
for idx, (word, count) in enumerate(total_word.items()):
    print(f"{idx:<3}{word:<{padding}}{count:>3}")
```

Putting it all together:

```
clear_word = ['a'] * 3 + ['ccc'] * 4 + ['bb'] * 10

total_word = {}
for word in clear_word:
    if word not in total_word:
        total_word[word] = 0
    total_word[word] += 1

padding = max(len(word) for word in total_word.keys()) + 1
for idx, (word, count) in enumerate(total_word.items()):
    print(f"{idx:<3}{word:<{padding}}{count:>3}")
```

your output is

> ```
> 0  a     3
> 1  ccc   4
> 2  bb   10
> ```

Answer (score 0):

If it is only about string formatting, you can prepare string similarly to:

```
arr = ['a', 'bb', 'ccc']

for i in range(len(arr)):
  print('{} {:4} {}'.format(i, arr[i], i+5))
```

I am using this site as a resource for string formatting https://pyformat.info/#string_pad_align

Answer (score 0):

I guess this is what your want:

Try this:

```py
clear_word = ['a','ccc','bb','ccc','a','ccc','bb','bb','a','bb','bb','bb','bb','bb','bb','bb','bb','bb','bb']
total_word = {}
for word in clear_word:
    if word not in total_word:
        total_word[word] = 0
    total_word[word] += 1

for i, k in enumerate(total_word):
    print("    {0:2} {1:3}     {2:5}".format(i, k, total_word[k]))
```

That is output:
[align output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/icNVU.png)

Comment: what a great code, thanks